# Timer does not calling with specified time

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I'm using timer control in web application.I use a div with a drop down which contain the values for  minutes like 10,20,30.by default div is invisible according to get data method div will visible. now using this drop down menu I will select the minutes and add the current time and set the Total time in Session variable. and get this calculated time and give the interval of timer now I want to visible my div according to specified time period using the tick event.my div is not display specified with specified time please help me out this issue.

```
private void BindControl()
{
    //ddlTime.Items.Clear();
    List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
    items.Add(new ListItem("10", "10"));
    items.Add(new ListItem("20", "20"));
    items.Add(new ListItem("30", "30"));
    ddlTime.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());

}
private void GetData()
{
    ClsCandidateManager ObjCandidateManager = new ClsCandidateManager();
    if ((ObjCandidateManager.CountInterviewScheduled() > 0))
    {
        divReminder.Visible = true;
        tmrReminder.Enabled = false;
        //if (ddlTime.SelectedIndex > 0)
        //{
        //    ClsSessionManager.SetInterval = (DateTime.Now + (ddlTime.SelectedValue * 1000);
        //}
    }

    DataTable dt = ObjCandidateManager.GetScheduledInterviews();
    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        grdInterviewInfo.DataSource = dt;
    }
    else
    {
        grdInterviewInfo.DataSource = ClsSingleton.BlankTable;
    }
    grdInterviewInfo.DataBind();
}


protected void tmrInterview_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    divReminder.Visible = true;
}
protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlTime.SelectedValue != null)
    {
        //DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        ClsSessionManager.SetInterval = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(ddlTime.SelectedValue));
        tmrReminder.Interval = (ClsSessionManager.SetInterval).Millisecond;
        divReminder.Visible = false;
        tmrReminder.Enabled = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: have you stepped through your code to ensure the tick event is being fired?

Comment: It would seem you are talking about a server side time but that won't do anything to the client. How are you managing the timer on the client (JavaScript) side?

Comment: hi  Tanner. yes my tick event is fired..

Answer (score -1):

i may of misunderstood what it is your trying to do but you don't actually start your timer anywhere in your code so your timer is never actually run, you need to use `tmrReminder.Start()` and you also need to setup a `new ElapsedEventHandler` ie

```
tmrReminder.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler('method to be run when time elapses');
```

Comment: The timer's being started at tmrReminder.Enabled = true;. The elapsed handler is not in the sample though.

Comment: tmrInterview_Tick is the event handler for when the timer elapses

Comment: no thats just enabling it to raise the Elapsed event handler you need to actually tell it to start by calling the tmrReminder.Start() method. @Tanner he doesnt tell the timer to actually call that method when the time has elapsed so the timer never calls it

Comment: Timer.Start internally calls Timer.Enabled = true.

Comment: did not realise that it also done that, but he still has no ElapsedEventHandler so it wont call the method he wants it to so the event is necessary